# Apt-get update issues on Linux Mint

Tags: linux, linux-mint, updates

I recently shifted from `Ubuntu 12.10` to `Linux Mint 10`.

The `kernel` version I am using is `2.6.35-22-generic`

When I try to update it using `sudo apt-get update`, I get the following error:

```
Ign file: binary/ Release.gpg
Ign file:/usr/share/local-repository/ binary/ Translation-en
Ign file:/usr/share/local-repository/ binary/ Translation-en_US
Ign file: binary/ Release
Ign file: binary/ Packages
Ign file: binary/ Packages
Get:1 http://ftp.us.debian.org testing Release.gpg [1,571B]
Hit http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ testing/contrib Translation-en
Ign http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ testing/contrib Translation-en_US
Hit http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ testing/main Translation-en
Ign http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ testing/main Translation-en_US
Hit http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ testing/non-free Translation-en
Hit http://packages.medibuntu.org maverick Release.gpg
Ign http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ testing/non-free Translation-en_US
Hit http://archive.canonical.com maverick Release.gpg
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com maverick-security Release.gpg
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-security/main Translation-en
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-security/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick Release.gpg
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick/main Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick/universe Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates Release.gpg
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-security/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-security/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-security/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-security/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-security/universe Translation-en
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-security/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ maverick/partner Translation-en
Ign http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ maverick/partner Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.canonical.com julia Release.gpg
Ign http://archive.canonical.com/ julia/partner Translation-en
Ign http://archive.canonical.com/ julia/partner Translation-en_US
Get:2 http://linux.dropbox.com lucid Release.gpg [489B]
Ign http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu/ lucid/main Translation-en
Ign http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu/ lucid/main Translation-en_US
Get:3 http://packages.linuxmint.com julia Release.gpg [197B]
Get:4 http://ftp.us.debian.org testing Release [147kB]
Hit http://repository.spotify.com stable Release.gpg
Ign http://repository.spotify.com/ stable/non-free Translation-en
Ign http://repository.spotify.com/ stable/non-free Translation-en_US
Ign http://ftp.us.debian.org testing Release
Ign http://packages.medibuntu.org/ maverick/free Translation-en
Hit http://ftp.us.debian.org testing/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates/main Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates/universe Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick Release
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com maverick-security Release
Hit http://archive.canonical.com maverick Release
Ign http://archive.canonical.com julia Release
Ign http://packages.medibuntu.org/ maverick/free Translation-en_US
Hit http://repository.spotify.com stable Release
Get:5 http://linux.dropbox.com lucid Release [2,599B]
Ign http://packages.medibuntu.org/ maverick/non-free Translation-en
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com maverick-security/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://archive.canonical.com julia/partner Sources
Ign http://packages.linuxmint.com/ julia/import Translation-en
Ign http://packages.linuxmint.com/ julia/import Translation-en_US
Ign http://packages.linuxmint.com/ julia/main Translation-en
Ign http://packages.linuxmint.com/ julia/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://packages.linuxmint.com/ julia/upstream Translation-en
Ign http://packages.linuxmint.com/ julia/upstream Translation-en_US
Ign http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free amd64 Packages
Ign http://packages.medibuntu.org/ maverick/non-free Translation-en_US
Hit http://ftp.us.debian.org testing/contrib amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Hit http://ftp.us.debian.org testing/non-free amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com maverick-security/restricted amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com maverick-security/universe amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com maverick-security/multiverse amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates Release
Ign http://archive.canonical.com julia/partner amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.canonical.com maverick/partner amd64 Packages
Ign http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free amd64 Packages
Hit http://packages.medibuntu.org maverick Release
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com maverick-security/main amd64 Packages
Ign http://archive.canonical.com julia/partner Sources
Hit http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free amd64 Packages
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com maverick-security/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com maverick-security/universe amd64 Packages
Get:6 http://linux.dropbox.com lucid/main amd64 Packages [1,148B]
Ign http://archive.canonical.com julia/partner amd64 Packages
Hit http://packages.medibuntu.org maverick/free amd64 Packages
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com maverick-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick/restricted amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Err http://archive.canonical.com julia/partner Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.150 80]
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com maverick-security/main amd64 Packages
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com maverick-security/restricted amd64 Packages
Err http://archive.canonical.com julia/partner amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.150 80]
Hit http://packages.medibuntu.org maverick/non-free amd64 Packages
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com maverick-security/universe amd64 Packages
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick/universe amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick/multiverse amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com maverick-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
Err http://security.ubuntu.com maverick-security/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com maverick-security/restricted amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com maverick-security/universe amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com maverick-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
Get:7 http://packages.linuxmint.com julia Release [12.1kB]
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/restricted amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/universe amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick/main amd64 Packages
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick/universe amd64 Packages
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/main amd64 Packages
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/universe amd64 Packages
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick/main amd64 Packages
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick/universe amd64 Packages
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/main amd64 Packages
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/universe amd64 Packages
Ign http://packages.linuxmint.com julia/main amd64 Packages
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick/restricted amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick/universe amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick/multiverse amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Ign http://packages.linuxmint.com julia/upstream amd64 Packages
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/universe amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com maverick-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Ign http://packages.linuxmint.com julia/import amd64 Packages
Ign http://packages.linuxmint.com julia/main amd64 Packages
Ign http://packages.linuxmint.com julia/upstream amd64 Packages
Ign http://packages.linuxmint.com julia/import amd64 Packages
Get:8 http://packages.linuxmint.com julia/main amd64 Packages [7,502B]
Get:9 http://packages.linuxmint.com julia/upstream amd64 Packages [12.6kB]
Get:10 http://packages.linuxmint.com julia/import amd64 Packages [5,637B]
Fetched 43.9kB in 3s (11.3kB/s)
W: GPG error: http://ftp.us.debian.org testing Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY AED4B06F473041FA NO_PUBKEY 8B48AD6246925553
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/dists/julia/partner/source/Sources.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.150 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/dists/julia/partner/binary-amd64/Packages.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.150 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick-security/main/binary-amd64/Packages.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick-security/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick-security/universe/binary-amd64/Packages.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick-security/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick/main/binary-amd64/Packages.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick/universe/binary-amd64/Packages.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick-updates/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick-updates/universe/binary-amd64/Packages.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick-updates/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

E: Some index files failed to download, they have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

My `sources.list` looks like this

```
deb http://packages.linuxmint.com/ julia main upstream import
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ maverick partner
deb http://packages.medibuntu.org/ maverick free non-free

# deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu maverick-getdeb apps
# deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu maverick-getdeb games

 # Debian Testing (currently Wheezy)

deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian testing main contrib non-free
deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ julia partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ julia partner
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ julia partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ julia partner
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ julia partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ julia partner
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ julia partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ julia partner
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ julia partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ julia partner
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ julia partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ julia partner
```

I am not updating it via a proxy connection. Any idea what the problem could be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Linux Mint 10 isn't supported any more](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=151&t=99411), and Ubuntu maverick (10.10) dropped out of support over a year ago.  It's therefore likely that the repos your installation wants have gone away.

Seeing as you were using a recent (12.10) version of Ubuntu, you might want to try Mint 14, the current version.

Comment: `sudo apt-get upgrade` does not seem to work either :(

Comment: Probably because of the same reason -- the `maverick` repos aren't on `archive.ubuntu.com` any more.

Comment: so, the only option is to download Linux Mint 14 and then try it? no other options?

Comment: If you have `do-release-upgrade` installed then you could try running that to upgrade to `natty` (you'll need to upgrade stepwise if you don't want to do a fresh install).  See instructions at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NattyUpgrades

Comment: I believe its easier to do a direct upgrade :)

Comment: @user2015933 yes, much! Why would you want to use a three year old version of the OS anyway?

Comment: http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2012/04/10/ubuntu-10-10-maverick-meerkat-end-of-life-reached-on-april-10-2012/ says 'Note that upgrades to version 11.04 and beyond are only supported in multiple steps'.

Comment: I installed it using a bootaable usb stick which was created using `unetbootin`

Answer (score 2):

You have two different types of error there, the `404 Not Found` errors are probably, as @Flup suggested, because you are using an old system and the repos have probably been taken off line since the versions are no longer supported. The GPG errors:

> W: GPG error: http://ftp.us.debian.org testing Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY AED4B06F473041FA NO_PUBKEY 8B48AD6246925553

just mean you need to import the GPG keys of the repositories.

To import the keys do:

```
sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com AED4B06F473041FA
sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com 8B48AD6246925553
```

Comment: did not work for me! I got the following error everytime I tried it.
gpg: keyserver timed out
gpg: keyserver receive failed: keyserver error

Comment: @vabhatia I just tried it and it works. Perhaps you were not connected to the internet when you tried it? Or perhaps the keyserver was down, try again, it should work.